# Bullet list types in Migradoc

Tags: migradoc

How can i give user defined ListType using Migradoc. I have found 6 types of Listtypes.

In those Bulletlist3 is the square but i need to give bigger size square so, how can i give that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot use custom bullet list symbols with MigraDoc.

When we needed this, we just added an empty paragraph, used AddFormattedText to add the bullet symbol (we also needed big squares), added a tab, then came the normal text.

Set the paragraph style properly as discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635220/1015447